# Query not comparing negative values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to compare two value in my query. When I am passing normal values then below query is working fine but when I am passing negative value in minus then I am not getting correct answer. How can I solve this.

```
IF value1 < min1 AND value1 > max1 AND  (lower(severity1) = lower('Severe-1') OR lower(severity1) = lower('Critical'))
    THEN
    update audit_ques_link SET line_stop = 0 where audit_question_id IN(SELECT max(audit_question_id) FROM audit_ques_link);
    RETURN QUERY Select cast(0 as numeric) as msg,cast('Stop line' as character varying), am.audit_id, ddl8.dd_value  as stageno,
        ddl1.dd_value as stage, ddl2.dd_value, ddl3.activity_id as activity_id, ddl4.dd_value as activity, 
        ddl5.dd_value as process, ddl3.product as product, ddl3.assembly as assembly, ddl6.dd_value as line_no,
        ddl7.dd_value as area
        from audit_ques_detail am 
        left join dd_type_details ddl1 on ddl1.dd_id= am.stage
        left join dd_type_details ddl2 on ddl2.dd_id= am.stage_no
        left join audit_master ddl3 on ddl3.audit_id= am.audit_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl4 on ddl4.dd_id= ddl3.activity_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl5 on ddl5.dd_id = ddl3.process
        left join dd_type_details ddl6 on ddl6.dd_id = ddl3.line_no
        left join dd_type_details ddl7 on ddl7.dd_id = ddl3.area
        left join dd_type_details ddl8 on ddl8.dd_id =  am.stage_no
        where audit_ques_id = (select question_id from audit_ques_link  order by audit_question_id desc limit 1);
    ELSE

    IF value1 < min1 OR value1 > max1
    THEN
    update audit_ques_link SET isCorrect = 0 where audit_question_id IN(SELECT max(audit_question_id) FROM audit_ques_link);
    ELSe
    update audit_ques_link SET isCorrect = 1 where audit_question_id IN(SELECT max(audit_question_id) FROM audit_ques_link);
    END IF;

    update audit_ques_link SET line_stop = 1 where audit_question_id IN(SELECT max(audit_question_id) FROM audit_ques_link);
    RETURN QUERY Select cast(1 as numeric) as msg,cast('Correct answer' as character varying), am.audit_id, ddl8.dd_value  as stageno,
        ddl1.dd_value as stage, ddl2.dd_value, ddl3.activity_id as activity_id, ddl4.dd_value as activity, 
        ddl5.dd_value as process, ddl3.product as product, ddl3.assembly as assembly, ddl6.dd_value as line_no,
        ddl7.dd_value as area
        from audit_ques_detail am 
        left join dd_type_details ddl1 on ddl1.dd_id= am.stage
        left join dd_type_details ddl2 on ddl2.dd_id= am.stage_no
        left join audit_master ddl3 on ddl3.audit_id= am.audit_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl4 on ddl4.dd_id= ddl3.activity_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl5 on ddl5.dd_id = ddl3.process
        left join dd_type_details ddl6 on ddl6.dd_id = ddl3.line_no
        left join dd_type_details ddl7 on ddl7.dd_id = ddl3.area
        left join dd_type_details ddl8 on ddl8.dd_id =  am.stage_no
        where audit_ques_id = (select question_id from audit_ques_link  order by audit_question_id desc limit 1);
    END IF;
```

Comment: What negative values are you passing that cause a problem?

Comment: any negative values like (-9, -.7, etc)

Comment: But what variables are you passing them in to? `value1`? `min1`? `max1`?

Comment: I am passing min1 and max1

Comment: is there any error or gives you incorrect out put ? Can you put in one example for working and not working case with expected and incorrect output ?